# Error "../../nsprpub: No such file or directory." when building Firefox on OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, mozilla

I followed a set of simple instructions on [Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build).

When I entered `make -f client.mk build`

I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/make  tier_nspr
tier_nspr:  config/nspr
/usr/bin/make export_tier_nspr
export_tier_nspr
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `config/nspr/Makefile'.
/usr/bin/make -C config/nspr export
/usr/bin/make -C ../../nsprpub export SHARED_LIBRARY= IMPORT_LIBRARY= SHARED_LIB_PDB= XP_DEFINE=-DlibVersionPoint='libVersionPoint$(LIBRARY_NAME)'
make: *** ../../nsprpub: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[5]: *** [export] Error 2
make[4]: *** [export_tier_nspr] Error 2
make[3]: *** [tier_nspr] Error 2
make[2]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

It is the first time I tried to build Firefox. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while attempting to build the Android version of Firefox. Making a clean clone of the source tree and re-building solved the problem for me.